# Beautiful Soup Not Finding Table

Tags: html, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm parsing data from this [website](https://www.hockey-reference.com/boxscores/202008140WSH.html#all_advanced).  I've parsed several things from the site, but for some reason, this particular page isn't finding one of the tables.  Here's a simplified code snippet which demonstrates the issue:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3 

import bs4 as bs
import requests

def get_soup(site):
    headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
    r = requests.get(site, headers=headers)
    #Always want a status code of 200, which means everything downloaded
    if r.status_code != 200:
        print(r.status_code)
        print("Invalid Status Code")
        exit(1)
    return bs.BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')

soup = get_soup("https://www.hockey-reference.com/boxscores/202008140WSH.html#all_advanced")
table = soup.find('table' , {'id' : "NYI_skaters"}).find('tbody').find_all('tr')
table = soup.find('table' , {'id' : "NYI_goalies"}).find('tbody').find_all('tr')
table = soup.find('table' , {'id' : "NYI_adv"}).find('tbody').find_all('tr')
```

The code finds the skaters and goalies table with no issues, but it doesn't find the _adv table, resulting in a NoneType error, since it's not finding the table.  I'm able to find a node which _adv resides under:

```
table = soup.find('div' , {'id' : "all_advanced"})
```

Underneath that div tag (all_advanced), there's some strange looking code, so I'm not sure if that has something to do with it.  I haven't had any issues with this particular site with other things, never needed to use selenium and they're fine with people scraping the data.  Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: Using panda.read_html doesn't find it either.  I was able to work around it by replacing all the "table =" above with:

```
for comment in soup.find_all(text=lambda text: isinstance(text, bs.Comment)):
    if comment.find("<table ") > 0:
        comment_soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(comment, 'html.parser')
        table = comment_soup.find('table' , {'id' : "NYI_adv"})
for player in table.find_all('tr' , {'class' : "ALLSH hidden"}):
    print(player.find('a')['href'])
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To load the table data from comment section, use this script:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, Comment

url = 'https://www.hockey-reference.com/boxscores/202008140WSH.html#all_advanced'
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'html.parser')

# normal tables:
# table_skaters = soup.select_one('table#NYI_skaters')
# table_goalies = soup.select_one('table#NYI_goalies')

# table loaded from Comment:
table_advanced = soup.select_one('#all_advanced').find_next(text=lambda t: isinstance(t, Comment))
table_advanced = BeautifulSoup(table_advanced, 'html.parser')

# print(table_advanced)

for row in table_advanced.select('tr.ALL5v5'):
    tds = [td.get_text(strip=True) for td in row.select('td, th')]
    print(*tds, sep='\t')
```

Prints:

```
Josh Bailey     1       9       21      30.0    -32.1   3       1       75.0    0       1
Mathew Barzal   3       12      9       57.1    7.8     3       6       33.3    0       0
Anthony Beauvillier     4       10      21      32.3    -29.1   4       1       80.0    1       1
Derick Brassard 1       8       6       57.1    7.1     6       8       42.9    3       0
Casey Cizikas   2       14      7       66.7    20.4    4       5       44.4    1       0
Cal Clutterbuck 5       14      8       63.6    16.6    4       5       44.4    3       0
Jordan Eberle   3       14      9       60.9    13.2    3       6       33.3    1       0
Andy Greene     0       9       13      40.9    -13.6   6       8       42.9    2       1
Leo Komarov     2       10      7       58.8    9.5     7       8       46.7    5       1
Nick Leddy      2       13      20      39.4    -18.8   4       8       33.3    0       1
Anders Lee      2       13      6       68.4    22.0    2       7       22.2    0       0
Matt Martin     2       9       7       56.2    6.2     0       2       0.0     4       0
Scott Mayfield  1       16      11      59.3    11.8    4       4       50.0    3       1
Brock Nelson    2       9       19      32.1    -27.9   3       1       75.0    2       0
Jean-Gabriel Pageau     3       13      9       59.1    10.6    9       10      47.4    4       0
Adam Pelech     3       15      13      53.6    3.6     8       4       66.7    2       1
Ryan Pulock     5       18      14      56.2    8.0     6       9       40.0    0       1
Devon Toews     4       19      15      55.9    7.8     4       7       36.4    1       4
TOTAL           45      43      51.1                            44.4    32      12
Travis Boyd     3       6       7       46.2    -3.1    3       5       37.5    0       1
John Carlson    5       19      14      57.6    14.0    5       12      29.4    2       1
Brenden Dillon  2       18      19      48.6    -0.4    7       2       77.8    0       3
Nic Dowd        1       3       6       33.3    -17.3   3       0       100.0   0       1
Lars Eller      1       17      21      44.7    -7.3    6       2       75.0    1       1
Carl Hagelin    1       7       8       46.7    -2.6    5       4       55.6    1       0
Garnet Hathaway 1       4       6       40.0    -10.0   3       0       100.0   2       0
Nick Jensen     0       3       12      20.0    -34.8   8       2       80.0    0       0
Michal Kempny   3       18      12      60.0    16.9    4       10      28.6    1       0
Ilya Kovalchuk  0       5       9       35.7    -15.7   3       7       30.0    3       0
Evgeny Kuznetsov        5       16      10      61.5    18.0    8       9       47.1    1       0
Dmitry Orlov    1       23      22      51.1    4.6     8       5       61.5    1       0
T.J. Oshie      4       21      19      52.5    6.7     5       2       71.4    2       1
Alex Ovechkin   8       16      13      55.2    9.4     8       9       47.1    4       0
Richard Panik   2       7       10      41.2    -9.5    5       1       83.3    0       0
Jonas Siegenthaler      1       5       11      31.2    -21.6   8       1       88.9    2       1
Jakub Vrana     3       13      16      44.8    -6.0    3       3       50.0    0       0
Tom Wilson      2       14      10      58.3    13.0    8       6       57.1    8       0
TOTAL           43      45      48.9                            55.6    28      9
```